# Which environment of CentOS 7 do i choose, so that i can properly install and demonstrate the uses of a squid proxy?

Tags: proxy, centos, centos7, squid

I am currently undertaking an assignment of which i have to demonstrate the features of squid proxy on CentOS 7. However when setting up CentOS7 in the installer, i am unsure of which environment to pick - Virtualization Host, Server with GUI etc, to ensure the squid proxy can be set up and works properly.

Comment: You can check your squid with: webmin . This is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix services and servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pick base setup and install squid using

> yum install squid

Squid will work fine however you might to adjust settings but this is regardless of what you've picked during installation